# Retrieving current link from InAppBrowser in Phonegap

Tags: url, cordova

As a new functionality in Phonegap Cordova 2.3.0, InAppBrowser helps to browse web within the app. My question is that how do i retrieve the URL currently opened when the browser is closed. I have tried event.url functionality as mentioned [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) but in vain.

Comment: That is the way to do it. What's not working?

Comment: I have been trying with it but it always return me null no matter what link i open in the browser and then close it.

Comment: Provide some more details, code, etc.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald hi i too have problem if we click on a link on innapp browser and redirect to a new url ath that time how to get the current url? is thr any methods?

Comment: @ArjunTRaj add the event listeners 'loadstop' and 'exit' .. on loadstop, store the url in session and on exit, retrieve url from that session object.